# How to pass any selected option value from a view to a controller ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code. I want to select a option and pass the value in controller.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="MobileNumber" class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                        <input asp-for="MobileNumber" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="MobileNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label asp-for="Gender" for="inputState">Gender</label>
                          <select asp-for="Gender" id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Please Choose...</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Other</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
```

This is Controller Action. I want to get select option value this action.

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                model.Resolve(_scope);
                await model.UserCreate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "User not create.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I suppose there is some `form` HTTP tag that wraps the those divs right? There should be a submit button for such form and it would trigger a POST request sending data from view to controller. Can you paste the whole html?

Comment: Thanks for relpy, Yes i have submit button, and controller

Comment: This view into a from . I;m edited my code , and share controller code. Please help me how to get value from controller

Comment: Can take a look at this page on how to post messages to a controller? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the full context of the **CreateModel** object, specifically what type is **Gender**, but I'm assuming it's string.
One thing that you are missing is defining values for the **select** options.

You need to do something similar to this in order to give a value for each option:

```
<select asp-for="Gender" id="inputState" class="form-control">
    <option selected>Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if it helped!